# Javascript: Storing the current time's timestamp value

Tags: javascript, django, timestamp

Is there a way to store the current timestamp in a Javascript variable? The reason is I want to compare Javascript's current time value with a Django time variable, and whenever the time matches, it will send a popup notification.

I guess reloading the page maybe every 3 seconds or so would work, but that seems extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here. It's not likely the times will ever match exactly unless you check every millisecond, but you can always check when the time is greater than the django variable, or within a certain range. This will check the time every three seconds.

```
var django = // Create a javascript date object from django timestamp here
var interval = setInterval(function(){checkTime()}, 3000);

function checkTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    if (d >= django) {
        //Do something here
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: i figured it out! this wasn't exactly the answer I was looking for (sorry for the bad wording in the question), but the thought process helped me figure out the solution. thanks a bunch!